# Analysis - Show that $f(a^n) = nf(a)$ for all natural numbers n.

Tags: analysis

The following is an example problem I am attempting to complete:

Let $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ be a mapping such that

$f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y$

Show that $f(a^n)=nf(a)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Given that $n\in\mathbb{N}$, I thought this might be something we could do using an induction. However, I am not quite sure if this is the right way to go.

I know that when $n=1, f(a^1) = f(a) = 1\cdot f(a)$.

Furthermore, if we assume $f(a^n) = nf(a)$, then

$$f(a^{n+1}) = f(a^n\cdot a) = f(a^n) + f(a) = nf(a) + f(a) = (n+1)f(a)$$

From here it seems I've shown that $f(n) $ implies $f(n+1)$. I think this is mostly sufficient but I am getting the feeling I am missing something or that perhaps I could have formatted the proof a bit differently so that it flows better. Is there anything else I have to add or is what I have sufficient?

Comment: That is sufficient =)

Comment: That's sufficient. Now replace $\mathbb N$ by $\mathbb Q$ and define the same function. Can you prove that $f(x^r) = rf(x)$ for every rational $r$? How about replacing $\mathbb Q$ by $\mathbb R$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is both completely sufficient and fairly elegantly written. Well done! As BolzWeir has pointed out, it is a fun exercise to use this fact to now prove the same statement for all integers (recommended first step) and then all rational numbers. Good luck!